# Detect which type of SSL Pinning is being used on Android Applications

Tags: applications, security

Is there a way to detect what the Android Application is using as SSL Pinning. Whether it is certificate Pinning , Public Key Pinning or Hash Pinning ?

I am doing a study on local Android Applications and would like to collect data on what type of Pinning these applications are using.

TIA

Comment: Reverse engineer the apps using Jadx, apktool, JEB, Ida, Ghidra, .... But that is more a topic for https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com Of course you need sufficient programming skills to understand the decompiled code. The more you know about Android development and reverse engineering the easier you will understand the decompiled code.

Comment: The [official documentation for Android Developer](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl#Pinning) mentions a little bit about this. Btw, I know an app that uses public-key pinning. However, there's no easy way except to reverse engineer the app and analyze the code.